# oracle converting columns to rows based on number of records for an id

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

```
select *
    from(select C_TYPE_ID_EXT, C_ID_EXT, 
               row_number() over (partition by I_INTRN order by rank1) as rank
           from (select I_INTRN , C_TYPE_ID_EXT,C_ID_EXT,
                     row_number() over (partition by I_INTRN order by I_INTRN) rank1
                  from dex.dex_ej_rmpm_id
        )
where rank<=3;
```

above query gives me the below output

```
rmpmid  C_TYPE_ID_EXT   C_ID_EXT    RANK
1             BEN         988-99      1
1             REGON       988-99      2
1             SIREN       988-99      3
2             BEN         988-99      1
2             REGON       988-99      2
2             SIREN       988-99      3
3             BEN         988-99      1
4             REGON       988-99      1
```

now i am looking for something as below by making changes in the above query

```
rmpmid  type1   id1        type2    id2     type3   id3
1        Ben    988-99     Regon    988-99  siren   988-99
2        Ben    988-99     Regon    988-99  siren   988-99
3        ben    988-99              
4        regon  988-99
```

i was trying to do this using Pivot option but unable to find solution
can somebody from the team help me out with this.

Comment: It would help if you showed what you had tried and why it didn't produce what you wanr.

Comment: thanks alex for looking into my query i tried as below            select *
    from(select C_TYPE_ID_EXT, C_ID_EXT, 
               row_number() over (partition by I_INTRN order by rank1) as rank
           from (select I_INTRN , C_TYPE_ID_EXT,C_ID_EXT,
                     row_number() over (partition by I_INTRN order by I_INTRN) rank1
                  from dex.dex_ej_rmpm_id
        )PIVOT
( MIN( C_ID_EXT ) as Type FOR C_TYPE_ID_EXT  IN (select  C_TYPE_ID_EXT  from  type))
where rank<=3;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select rmpmid,
       max(case when rank = 1 then C_TYPE_ID_EXT end) as type1,
       max(case when rank = 1 then C_ID_EXT end) as id1,
       max(case when rank = 2 then C_TYPE_ID_EXT end) as type2,
       max(case when rank = 2 then C_ID_EXT end) as id2,
       max(case when rank = 3 then C_TYPE_ID_EXT end) as type3,
       max(case when rank = 3 then C_ID_EXT end) as id3
from (select C_TYPE_ID_EXT, C_ID_EXT, rmpmid,
             row_number() over (partition by I_INTRN order by I_INTRN) as rank
      from dex.dex_ej_rmpm_id
     )
where rank <= 3
group by rmpmid;
```

Two comments:  your query does not have `rmpmid` although the results do.  I added it in.  Second, you don't need two levels of `row_number()`.  The inner one should do what you want.

Comment: that worked great thank you very much **Gordon Linoff**